# Deadlock Detection in Distributed Systems: Deadlock victim not recognised when using two different SQL-Server on different machines

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactionscope, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I have a reproducible case where NO deadlock victim is detected.

The configuration is as follows:

- Database 1 runs on SQL Server 1 on Machine 1
- Database 2 runs on SQL Server 2 on Machine 2

The MSDTCs on Machine 1 and Machine 2 are configured correctly and transactions across multiple databases generally work without problems.

My program is written in C# and works with .NET Framework 4.8. If I now open two TransactionScopes and perform CRUD operations between Database 1 and Database 2, a deadlock occurs, which is **not** recognized by the MSDTCs. Both TransactionScopes block until the database connection times out, which throws an exception.

The same situation with the following configuration results in the MSDTC correctly detecting a deadlock and determining a deadlock victim. One TransactionScope can complete and the other fails immediately because of the deadlock victim exception:

- Database 1 runs on SQL Server 1 on Machine 1
- Database 2 runs on SQL Server 1 on Machine 1

The only difference is that in the second case only **one** MSDTC is involved in the transactions. I suspect that in the first case the deadlock situation is not recognized because **two** MSDTC are involved. Is there a configuration for the MSDTC that I need to apply so that all deadlocks are detected?

My Code looks like this:

```
public class TransactionProblem
{        
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void Execute()
    {
        var task_A = new Task(ExecuteTransaction);
        var task_B = new Task(ExecuteTransaction);

        // start task_A
        task_A.Start();

        // start stask_B -> wait until task_A triggers the signal to force the deadlock
        _are.WaitOne(); 
        task_B.Start();

        // wait for both tasks to be completed
        Task.WaitAll(task_A, task_B);
    }

    private void ExecuteTransaction()
    {
        // local helper method
        TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
        {
            var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead };
            return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions);
        }

        using (var scope = CreateTransactionScope())
        {
            using (Context contextSrc = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateForeignDb())
            {
                using (Context contextDst = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateOwnDb())
                {
                    // update data
                    var item = contextSrc.MyTable.Where(t => t.State == 1).FirstOrDefault();
                    var itemToUpdate = contextDst.MyTable.Where(i => item.Id == i.Id).FirstOrDefault(); // here task_B waits for task_A
                    itemToUpdate.Amount = item.Amount;
                    item.State = 0;

                    // save destination DB
                    contextDst.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                    contextDst.SaveChanges();
                }

                _are.Set();
                // wait to give task_B the chance to execute the "update data" code above to force the deadlock
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // save source DB
                contextSrc.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                contextSrc.SaveChanges(); // here task_A waits for task_B
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
public class MyTable
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public short Amount { get; set; }
    public byte State { get; set; }
}
```

SQL-Server Activity Monitor:
[image: SQL-Server Activity Monitor]

Deadlock Victim will be detected:
[image: Deadlock Victim will be detected]

Deadlock Victim will be **NOT** detected:
[image: Deadlock Victim will be NOT detected]

Comment: Do a search on Google for following : "sql transact chain deadlock"

Comment: The deadlock isn't logged in the SQL Server Profiler because it isn't detected. That's my problem. The MSDTCs or/and SQL Servers don't even know that there is a deadlock even though one exists (see printscreen "Activity Monitor" above). The deadlock is only detected if everthing (Database 1 and Database 2) is running on one Machine with one SQL-Server.

Comment: I think that is the issue.  You need to find out why the SQL Server isn't detecting the condition.  Read the documentation in the Google search.

Comment: I spent already 60 hours looking for a solution or finding out the cause.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: **distributed deadlocks** is the keyword that describes the problem best. But i didn't found a solution for SQL Server so far.